# Matching against longest leading substring

Tags: algorithm, haskell, search

I'm looking to return the best match of a list against a collection of lists.

`x` matches against a list in the collection if the list in the collection of length n matches the first n elements of `x`.

e.g. `[1,2,3]` matches against `[1,2]` but `[1,2]` does not match against `[1,2,3]`.

I want the function to return the "best" match, that is, the match that is the longest.

e.g.

```
bestMatch [1,2,3,3] [[1],[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,2],[1,2,3,4]] == Just [1,2,3]
```

Obviously a list here isn't the best data structure, and I'd rather use a standard structure and search rather than roll my own, any ideas what I should be using and how?

I don't think hash tables will work because the matches aren't exact. I then thought about searching against an ordered tree, but it has the problem that if I search for `[1,2,100]`, I'll get `[1,2,99]`, `[1,2,98]`, ... etc before getting the correct answer, `[1,2]`. Could use a hash of hashes (and so-on down the tree) but that seems like a lot of overhead.

(A linear search list based implementation is [here](http://ideone.com/aKpl3A))

Comment: A Trie seems appropriate.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are providing only a link to the code and not the code directly in the question? To me it seems like you are just hurting easiness of copy & pasting and highlighting (ideone gets it wrong)... sure a link to ideone may be useful but I don't see any reason not to paste the code *also* in the question.

Comment: BTW you are mistaken about the ordered tree, you do not have to check that many elements.  If `[1,1] .. [1,100] and [2,1] .. [2,100]` are in the tree, then to get to `[2,1]` you'd need to check, say, `[1,100]`, `[2,50]`, `[2,25]`, `[2,12]`, `[2,6]`, `[2,3]`, `[2,1]` -- i.e. a logarithmic number of elements.  This is usually pretty fast: the logarithm of a billion is only 30.  Still I agree with Nico that a trie seems perfect -- then you can even have infinitely many elements! :-)

Answer (score 3):

A *trie* would be a good solution. In your case, values would be just `()`, marking that a given node corresponds to an end of a list. Then, given a list, you'll just traverse the trie as far down as possible, and the last encountered value will mark the longest matched list.

A `ByteString` based trie in `Data.Trie` offers [`match`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-trie-0.2.4.1/docs/Data-Trie.html#v:match), which seems to be exactly what you're looking for (if 8-byte chars keys would be sufficient for you):

```
-- | Given a query, find the longest prefix with an associated value in 
-- the trie, returning that prefix, it's value, and the remaining string.
match :: Trie a -> ByteString -> Maybe (ByteString, a, ByteString)
```

There is also another package [list-tries](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-tries), which has more generic keys. I'm not sure if there is an exact function like `match` above, but definitely it'd be possible to implement one.